# How do I replace an old-style ("wide screw posts") garage T-lock handle?

Tags: garage, lock

My garage features an old-style T-handle very similar to **[Prime-Line GD 52169](http://www.prime-line-products.com/home4.wcs?nMenuid=1060&cProd=GD&cSProd=010&cItem=GD+52169)** or **[National Hardware V7643](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00176KWU4)**, except that the distance between the hole centers is 1-3/4".

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find replacement handles anywhere - the only ones available have the distance of 1-1/2". Is there any way or trick to replace the T handle without drilling new holes and replacing most of the lock?

The only part that has similarly distanced holes is an L-handle (**[Prime-Line GD 52123](http://www.prime-line-products.com/home4.wcs?nMenuid=1060&cProd=GD&cSProd=010&cItem=GD+52123)**), but apart from having a different shape it also seems to feature real holes on the sides, not the shafts. I am not sure if it would fit the T-lock assembly.

[image]

Where can I find a replacement handle?